# string layout on iPhone5 and 6

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, portrait

I am new to cocos2d v2.3, I am creating an demo game, but I have problem with iPhone5 and iPhone6, I simply add an background image to a scene, it displays like below. my image is 3072 × 4096, the default scaling is 4, it works well on iPhone4, can anyone tell me why?

[image]

Comment: You didn't say what the problem is on iPhone 5 and 6.